# AJAX data post is not received correctly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two files in my site home.php (view) and home.php (controller). In home.php (view) I have a jquery function that sends an AJAX request (it's mostly taken from the W3 jquery/AJAX example). In home.php (controller) I have a PHP variable that should accept the posted value form (view), but it doesn't. I've put an echo to check the value, but nothing appears. Is there any problem with my code?

**home.php (view)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.post("home.php",
                {
                    name:"George"
                });
        });
    });
```

**home.php (controller)**

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo ($name);
```

Checking Firebug's console the POST has a response that is comprised of the whole HTML code of home.php (view) and post parameters: **name**    George

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document (which is what the output of the PHP program is)!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't doing anything with `data` in your success function.

It isn't going to be visible on the page unless you add the data to the page.

Comment: The function was just a leftover I forgot to delete. Corrected. I just want $name take the value "George".

Comment: OK, so now you've deleted the function, you no longer have a function doing nothing with the response and instead you have nothing doing nothing with the response. That's a step backwards.

Comment: I don't have much experience in coding whatsoever, could you please explain what do I need to do to get what I want or is it too complicated?

Comment: Put the function back. Do something with the `data` argument that it had.